# Front-end AJAX request not working in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm writing a WordPress plugin (using the boilerplate recommended in the official documentation) and I need to incorporate an AJAX request to fill a DataList. I’m following the WP convention of sending my AJAX requests to “admin-ajax.php”.

My problem is that after doing everything “by the book” I can’t get it to work: the response from the server is always 0 (The default one). The server-side method to handle the request is not being triggered. I think it’s not being “hooked” at all. And I know the request enters the “admin-ajax” file.

The weird thing is that when I hook this method to “init” and process all AJAX requests in this function, it works perfectly. So, I’m pretty sure the problem is in the dynamic “wp_ajax_{$action}” and “wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}” hooks. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Here’s an extract of my code:

PHP

```
<?php

private function define_public_hooks() {
    $plugin_public = new SR_Public($this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version());
    $this->loader->add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_scripts');
    $this->loader->add_action('wp_ajax_sr_get_titles', $plugin_public, 'process_get_titles');
    $this->loader->add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sr_get_titles', $plugin_public, 'process_get_titles');
}

public function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        $this->plugin_name,
        PLUGIN_DIR_URL . 'public/js/sr-public.js',
        array('jquery'),
        $this->version
    );

    wp_localize_script(
        $this->plugin_name,
        'localizedData',
        array(
            'ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'nonce'   => wp_create_nonce('sr_get_titles'),
        )
    );
}

public function process_get_titles() {
    if ((!empty($_POST['action'])) && ($_POST['action'] === 'sr_get_titles')) {
        check_ajax_referer('sr_get_titles');

        // Load some data in $some_array...

        wp_send_json($some_array);
    }
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var titleInput = $("#sr-title");
    var titleDataList = $("#sr-requested-titles");

    function ajaxRequest() {
        var userInput = titleInput.val();

        if (userInput.trim() !== "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: localizedData.ajaxUrl,
                data: {_ajax_nonce: localizedData.nonce, action: "sr_get_titles", user_input: userInput},
                success: processSuccessResponse
            });
        }
    }

    function processSuccessResponse(data) {
        if (data) {
            titleDataList.empty();

            data.forEach(function(item) {
                titleDataList.append($("<option>").val(item));
            });
        }
    }

    titleInput.keyup(ajaxRequest);

});
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for status, data sent, data returned etc. Will help sort out if it is server side or client side issue

Comment: Thanks, @charlietfl, but that's just the thing, every aspect in the browser's dev bar seems ok. All the headers are sent fine, with every value I want to send. I get a 200 response code, and yet the returned data is always 0, wich is the WP default when no function was hooked to "wp_ajax_($action)" or "wp_ajax_nopriv_($action)". It's driving me crazy, 'cause I got it working fine if I don't send the AJAX request to "admin-ajax.php".

Comment: @Alex_89 - Just put wp_die(); at the end of your ajax function before json output

Comment: @Jaydp - The built-in function wp_send_json() handles the ending of the response function. I mean, it already executes the "die()" routine that is mandatory at the end. It's an alternative to encoding and echoing the JSON, plus, you don't need to worry about exiting the code. Again, this code works perfectly hooked anywhere else, so the problem must be in the hook itself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: AJAX processing is done in two separate invocations of the server. The first invocation sends the page that will make the AJAX request. This invocation should enqueue the scripts for sending the AJAX request. The second invocation is done when the server receives the AJAX request. This invocation should have the add actions for wp_ajax. To be clear the enqueue scripts and add action wp_ajax should not be in the same block of code. In particular, you should not be enqueuing scripts in the second invocation.

Comment: The reason it works with init is init is called in both invocations. But, this is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: @magenta - I think I understand what you mean, and I'm pretty sure that's the solution to my problem. But, where do you suggest I define the "wp_enque_scripts" and the "wp_ajax" hooks so that they are in separate code blocks? Keep in mind that I'm following a specific plugin boilerplate way of structuring my code: I define all my public hooks in the private "define_public_hooks()" method. Where else would I do it and still follow this convention? 1000 thanks, btw.

Comment: For front end AJAX the action 'wp_enqueue_scripts' is only executed when the server is sending a front-end page. is_admin() is true when the server is servicing an AJAX requests so it is often used to conditionally execute the add_action( 'wp_ajax...'). These are not the most efficient conditions but they will work. As you understand the process better you will find more restrictive conditions specific to your case.

Comment: You can put everything in a function define_public_hooks() which must always be called in both invocations but conditionally execute the appropriate code for the first or second invocation.

Comment: I'm sorry, @magenta, but don't fully get what you mean. In my **define_public_hooks()** method should I do this: **if (is_admin())** {
    $this->loader->add_action('wp_ajax_sr_get_titles', $plugin_public, 'process_ajax_requests');
    $this->loader->add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sr_get_titles', $plugin_public, 'process_ajax_requests');
} **else** {
    $this->loader->add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_public, 'enqueue_scripts');
}

Comment: I am sorry, but my statement 'To be clear the enqueue scripts and add action wp_ajax should not be in the same block of code.' is totally wrong as you actually have 'add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ...' which means enqueue_scripts() is conditionally executed for front-end pages only as the action 'wp_enqueue_scripts' is conditionally executed only for front-end pages. So I think your code is almost correct. You should embed your add_action( 'wp_ajax_...', ... ) in an if (is_admin()) block and make sure define_public_hooks() is always called.

Comment: I think the real problem is define_public_hooks() is being called only when the server is sending the front-end page and not being called on the second invocation when admin-ajax.php is used.

Comment: Right, I had forgotten that **wp_enque_scripts** is only called for the front-end as opposed to **admin_enqueue_scripts**. I updated my code, as per your suggestion, but I still keep getting the 0 response. I think you're on the right track with this, but I don't get why **define_public_hooks** needs to be called again. Once I hook **wp_ajax_** on my plugin start-up, why does it need to run again?

Comment: BTW, I can't wrap my head around this "2 invocations" concept. Do you think you could point me to some online resource/explanation to have a better, deeper understanding of how AJAX "really" works for WP? There's not even a mention to that in the Codex. Thank you so much, @magenta, for taking the time to answer my questions. You're amazing!

Comment: In the first invocation the front-end page is served. This page contains the JavaScript. After this page is served PHP stops running and any add_action's will be forgotten. The AJAX requests may happen many minutes later. When the HTTP server receives this request it starts the PHP server again. But this second invocation has no memory on what has been done on the first invocation. Although, the HTTP server runs continuously, the PHP server does not. The HTTP server starts the PHP server when it receives a request. The PHP server serves the request and dies and forgets.

Comment: As to why this is not working how is your function define_public_hooks called.

Comment: Bufff, sorry, I finally found what was wrong with my code. It actually has nothing to do with the snippet I posted in my question, that's are more or less fine. You just gave me a great hint, @magenta, by asking me how **define_public_hooks** was called. The thing is that I have a **plugin-admin** class and a **plugin-public** class (which in turn define their specific hooks) and I was conditionally loading them for the admin and public sides respectively. Since **admin-ajax.php** defines the **WP_ADMIN** global constant, my plugin wasn't loading the public hooks for the AJAX requests. Thanks!